# What does the expression something like "Verreck du Ass" mean?

Tags: phrase

I heard someone say something that sounded like "Verreck du Ass".  I'm sure it's not good!

I looked up verrecken and know that is a slang word for die.  I must have misunderstood "Ass" - I only know it to be the past tense of eat or an Ace playing card.  What is the actual expression?

Comment: Could »Ass« have been »Assi«?

Comment: @Raketenolli "Aas", not "Assi".

Comment: @Uwe: Do you have any evidence it was "Aas" in this case rather than "Assi"? At least in my limited experience, the latter seems to be the more common insult by orders of magnitude, and therefore was my very first assumption, as well.

Comment: "Verreck Du Aas" is a fixed phrase. Compare the number of Google hits for "Verreck Du Aas" vs. "Verreck Du Assi".

Comment: "past tense of eat" - the past tense of _essen_ (to eat) is _aß_ (with long _a_), not _ass_, but it sounds like _Aas_ (carrion), the word you heard.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm sure it's not good!

Yes, that's not good. It's hate speech.

> I looked up verrecken and know that is a slang word for die.

Yes, that's also correct. It's imperative for *die*.

> I must have misunderstood "Ass" - I only know it to be the past tense of eat or an Ace playing card. What is the actual expression?

The actual expression is most probably **Aas** which is translated to English as [carrion](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/carrion).

Funny enough, that doesn't make any sense at all, since we can consider that *carrion* refers to dead meat already, so the *"Verreck"* is going completely into the void.

As most of that kind of hate speech, the people posting such messages wheresoever aren't well aware of the simplest grammatical or any contextual connotations.

I hope I can make you feel better by exposing the general dumbness of such people, who don't even know the basic knowledge of their native language, but claim or blame others to miss such basic stuff.

Comment: With a bit of Googling I found that some people also use the expression in a humorous way when someone is sneezing, instead of "Gesundheit". So I think you are a bit too harsh in your judgement.

Comment: Thank you, both!

Comment: Usually, hate speech isn't used for speech used to express hatred towards the listener, but it's a legal term for speech expressing hatred of a particular group of people.  ([Marriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hate%20speech)) (Usually people of a specific ethnicity, religion, gender, sexual orientation etc., not just "my neighbors" or something like that.) Also, for what it's worth, I think most people who call another person "Aas" are perfectly aware of the fact that that person is, in fact, alive, so asking them to die isn't as redundant as you make it sound.

Comment: MY first instinct was that [As] is northern German. (Because the rare occasions when I hear that saying is from people who knwo Platt). But "Ass" would mean "Achse" (axis) thus makes no sence here and "Aas" also means "Aas" (carrion) so even if the saying has northern German roots, it still doubles up on dead meat.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is *"Verreck(e), Du Aas"*. *"Verrecken"* means *"to die miserably"*.
*"Aas"*, literally *"carrion"*, *"dead animal body"*, is a very traditional
and a bit old-fashioned insult, primarly for a dishonorable, malicious, perfidious person.

Combining both, *"Verreck(e), Du Aas"* is a curse. Something like
*"Die, Motherfucker"*. If you read it in early 20th century texts,
it means exactly that.

That usage is outdated, though.
If you hear it today, it's most likely a humorous alternative for
*"Gesundheit!"* when somebody sneezes.
This is a bit similar to wishing *"Hals- und Beinbruch"*, or in English,
*"break a leg":* There are old superstitions that the gods of fate
may intentionally do the opposite of whatever you wish, so in order
to fool them, you invert your wish yourself.

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know that the expression was used in German literature. Can you give examples? An Internet search provided two occurences: 1) In Hans Fallada's "Jeder stirbt für sich allein" (quotation: "Goebbels, du Aas, verrecke"). 2) In Joseph Goebbels' "Michael" (I didn't know that he wrote a novel ...)

Comment: Sorry, I was off by one century. The phrase  seems to have been popular (in the original pejorative sense) in particular between WW I and WW II. In addition to quotations you found see for instance [this text from Remarque](https://books.google.de/books?id=bqc7DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT155&ots=yLGkfpw7-d&dq=verrecke%20aas&hl=de&pg=PT155#v=onepage&q=verrecke%20aas&f=false), [this diary entry](https://www.zeit.de/1962/27/schauplatz-berlin/komplettansicht), or the testimony reported [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_S%C3%BClt).

Comment: Is that humorous alternative a regional thing? I've never heard it in such context.

Comment: @npst Perhaps, but I don't know where it's used and where it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it's clearly a *calque* from the French, *Crève, charogne!*, with *Crève!* being the imperative of *crever*, to die (of animals) and *charogne*, *Aas*. *Charogne* can easily be used figuratively to refer to humans.  Baudelaire famously entitled one of his pieces *A une charogne*.  It's very disparaging.  The same is true for *charognard*, *Aasfresser*, to refer to people that don't hesitate to speak ill or otherwise take undue advantage of the dead.  It's obvious *Aas* and *Aasfresser* do not lend themselves to such figurative uses to the same extent that they do in French.

Comment: In German "Aasgeier" is a common word to denote an "exploiter" or a "profiteer". See https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/Aasgeier.

Comment: This answer is difficult to understand for people who don't speak French. Could you please edit it to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

My guess for the second part would be that you misheard the word "Arsch" as in "verreck du Arsch" which means "kick the bucket, asshole" instead of "Ass".

By the way, the past tense of eat is "aß", not "ass".

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers suggest, most likely you heard "Verrecke, du Aas". Using "Aas" in such a context has the same meaning as in French (see petitrien's comment). There are quite a number of well-known phrases like "Du freches Aas" or "Du faules Aas". Look at https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aas - Bedeutungen [4]. Also see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aas.